# Error consuming .Net Standard NuGet package from Visual Studio 2015 project

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

I have a .Net Standard 2.0 class library project created in Visual Studio 2017, to which I generate a NuGet package (by checking the "Generate NuGet Package on Build" option in the project properties).
I have another project which targets .Net Framework 4.6.1 and I want it to reference my NuGet package. When I do, I get the following error:

```
You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author
```

(The funny thing is that I'm the package author... :-) )

Note that if I reference the DLL directly it works without a problem. It's just when I try to add the reference as a NuGet package that I get this error.

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: which Nuget version is installed into vs 2015?

Comment: NuGet 3.6 and above is needed if you use VS2015, https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/24

Comment: Thanks @LexLi! I installed NuGet 3.6 and then I got a message `To reference a library that targets .NET Standard 1.5 or higher, you need to install the .NET Standard Build Support extension for the .NET Framework from https://aka.ms/netstandard-build-support-netfx` in the output window. After installing the extension I restarted VS and viola! the package was added to my project. You're welcome to write it as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: I also had this issue: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1539 but the mentioned workaround resolved it.

Comment: Indeed a duplicate. Don't know how I missed it. Though the solution is not in the marked answer.